# Rocketchat is half-dark and half-light after a restart

Tags: dark-mode

Although the settings say 'dark mode', the left hand channel pane is in dark mode, and the right hand messages pane is in light mode.

Going to 'My Account' reveals that the current setting is for dark mode.  Changing it to light mode still results in the left hand channel pane being dark while the right hand messages pane is light.  Changing it to dark mode again still results in the left hand channel pane being dark while the right hand messages pane is light.

Forcing a refresh still results in the application being half-dark, half-light.

I do not have enough microcurrency to purchase the 'rocketchat' tag, but the name of the application affected by this is Rocket.chat.

Comment: Rocketchat is a desktop application, not a web application.  Thank you for your interest.

Comment: My advice of NOT creating a tag is sound.  What version are you using?  When I searched for RocketChat, I of course found the same project, and it's description let me to believe it was a web application written in JavaScript.  So my original comment wasn't without merit.

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/pbaity/rocketchat-dark-mode) to achieve the dark mode by chance?

Comment: No.  I am using the standard client.